# AJAX success funtion can be seen in console but doesn't actually alert

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, and I built simple AJAX function , I see "hello" in the console, but it doesn't actually alert anything in Chrome. Does anyone know the reason. Thanks for interest.

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".myTestLink").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                    return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
                },
            url: 'insert-ajax',
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

---

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::post('/insert-ajax', 'myTestController@testingsomething');
```

---

**myTestController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class myTestController extends Controller
{
    public function testingsomething()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch `dataType: 'json',` to `dataType: 'text',` when making the ajax call. Alert can't handle the json response.